# Can't browse any web page without being verified

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browsing

Every time I tried to browse a web page , there is a request for being verified whether I am a robot or not . After I check the mark , that I am not a robot  , then a question is appeared like check all the images with river , grass etc . Is there any way , that I can skip this ? This occurs every time , even if I refreshed the page .

My OS is ubuntu 16.04

Browser is chrome

I am not using any proxy service  or trying to hide my identity .

And trust me , I am not a robot at all .

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of one of the verification pages? Some services like Cloudflare will redirect you to these, but if it's showing up on *all* pages, something's very wrong.

Comment: To get an answer to your question, please find all the rivers in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndKMj.png).

Comment: @MikeyT.K. , I get this in 99% of the page . Even after verification , if I refresh the page , it asked me again . Sorry , I didn't post any screenshot , but Michael Frank , posted the exact screenshot in his comment .

Comment: If it's Cloudflare related like @MikeyT.K. suggested, you can see if your public IP address has been put on the naughtly list by entering it into this site: http://www.projecthoneypot.org/search_ip.php

Comment: Check whether your IP is blacklisted or not. If it's blacklisted then will provide you some solution to un-blacklist it.